# Getting results as JSON from BigQuery with google-cloud-python

Tags: python, json, google-bigquery, google-cloud-platform

I'm querying BigQuery via `google-cloud-python` as follows:

```
client = bigquery.Client()

query = """SELECT * FROM `{dataset}.{table}`
  WHERE id=@id LIMIT 1""".format(dataset=dataset,
                                 table=table)

param = ScalarQueryParameter('id', 'STRING', id)
query = client.run_sync_query(query, query_parameters=[param])
query.use_legacy_sql = False
query.timeout_ms = 1000
query.run()

assert query.complete

try:
    results = query.rows[0]
except IndexError:
    results = None
```

This returns data like:

```
[
    "Tue, 11 Apr 2017 03:18:52 GMT",
    "A132",
    "United Kingdom",
    [
        {
            "endDate": "2012-12-05",
            "startDate": "2011-12-27",
            "statusCode": "Terminated"
        }
    ]
]
```

The repeated field has been converted to JSON. But I want the rest of the data to be converted to JSON as well. I could implement this myself by examining `query.schema` but it seems like this should be in the library since it already happens for repeated elements.

How can I get BigQuery query results formatted as JSON using this library? E.g.:

```
{
    "timestamp": "Tue, 11 Apr 2017 03:18:52 GMT",
    "id": "A132",
    "country": "United Kingdom",
    [
        {
            "endDate": "2012-12-05",
            "startDate": "2011-12-27",
            "statusCode": "Terminated"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As it turns out, the code is simple enough:

```
field_names = [f.name for f in query.schema]

try:
    raw_results = query.rows[0]
    zipped_results = zip(field_names, raw_results)
    results = {x[0]: x[1] for x in zipped_results}
except IndexError:
    results = None
```